# Sql - Como fazer nome ou sobrenome ser único

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sqlite, sqlite3

Gente, é o seguinte tenho uma tabela chamada em sqlite, e eu quero o seguinte eu não quero que dados se repita, porém se alguém com um nome e sobrenome for cadastrado, quero que uma pessoa com o nome igual possa ser cadastrado mas o sobrenome tem que ser diferente, ou então nome diferente e o sobrenome igual. Vou dar um exemplo alguém com o nome

```
Letícia Almeida
```

É cadastrada no banco, então quero que uma pessoa com o nome

```
Letícia Ferreira
```

Também possa ser cadastrada, e que alguém com o nome

```
Mateus Almeida
```

Possa ser cadastrado, quero poder cadastrar uma pessoa mesmo que o nome já tenha sido utilizado exceto se o sobrenome também não for o mesmo, ou o sobrenome igual mais com nome diferente, exemplo do Mateus e a primeira Letícia, que tem nomes diferentes mais sobrenomes iguais. Me perdoem a qualidade da pergunta sou novo aqui e tô tentando explicar bem.

**Minha tabela:**

```
db.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users(
Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
User TEXT, Password TEXT, 
Nome TEXT, 
Sobrenome TEXT, 
UNIQUE(Nome,Sobrenome) ON CONFLICT REPLACE)");
```

Bom, estou usando node js por isso db.run e etc, bom enfim, na hora em que eu vou fazer o insert depois de alguns insert ele pula alguns números do id que é auto incrementavel em algum momento, aparentemente não tem um momento específico.

Comment: A chave "unique" te garante isto mas em sistema real isto não seria viável pois existem homonimos , poderiacatécter um índice por nome mas não único , o id "pula" pois alguns inserts podem ter falhado.

Comment: Então ... Mas não quero ter que cadastrar o mesmo usuário com os mesmos dados que já existe, até porque esses são onde os dados dos meus usuários estão, não poder haver 2 logins iguais com os mesmos dados no banco, entende?

Comment: A unique está correta o que não é usual e ela para nome , em geral se usa o COF ou o email para esta chave alternativa , desconheço todavia o comportamento do comando ON CONFLICT.

Comment: Mas se eu usasse o email para a unique, eu poderia ter uma pessoa com o mesmo nome e sobrenome com email diferente? Não sei se os sites de hoje em dia fazem isso, queria fazer de um jeito bonito e eficiente. E o on conflict é um "comando" especial do sqlite.

Comment: Homonimos ocorrem , emails os provedores nãk permitem iguais.

Comment: Okay obrigado vou usar essa dica.